# PHP MySQL two while lists, the second list takes the value of the previous list where the both lists are dynamic (takes the value from the database)

Tags: php, mysql, list, dynamic

the lists are for "Categories" and "Sub-Categories" i want if the user select the first category then the second list will display all the sub-categories that related to the selected category, am using PHP and MySQL,

this is my fisrt list code:

```
 <?php
  require("connect.php");
  $extract = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY catg_code ASC") or die (mysql_error());
  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($extract);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($extract))
  {
   $catgname = $row['catg_name'];
   $id =       $row['catg_code'];
   echo "<option value='$id' onClick='$var=$id' >  $catgname </option> ";
  }
 ?>
```

this is my second list code:

```
<?php
    require("connect.php");
    //$select4 = $_POST['select2']; 
    $extract = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE catg_code='$var' ORDER BY subCatg_code ASC") or die (mysql_error());
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($extract);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($extract))
    {
        $scatgname = $row['subCatg_name'];
        $sid =       $row['subCatg_code'];
        echo "<option name='mm' value='$sid'> $scatgname </option> ";
    }
?>
```

the tables in database includes (categories, subcategories and products) category includes (catg_code and catg_name)
subCategories table include (subcatg_code, subCatg_name and catg_code)

Comment: Please, please reformat this. It's practically unreadable, and I can only guess what it is you're asking.

Comment: Ears hurt and you leave alot to peoples imagination ;)

Comment: Am new what should i do .. this is my first time :(?

Comment: You should learn the basics first. PHP is a server-side language, Javascript is client-side. You're trying to mix both (ie. put PHP code in your javascript onClick event), which of course doesn't work. You'll have to look into AJAX to make this work for you...

Comment: can i make the onClick function to reload the page but keeps the value selected?

Comment: like in many websites, when you select your country then the second list will be changed and the whole page reloaded, then the second list display only the places in that country

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how about primary and foreign keys.
If you have a reference to the main category from your subcategory table you would only need to run the query once. Have a read up on join queries such as inner join and outer join there are plenty of tutorials out there (Google mysql joins).